# Immediate binding of Javascript object-method for event handling

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I would like to use an event handler function as part of a Javascript object. I want to bind "this" inside the event handler to the object it is a method of, since the "this" inside an event handler is usually automatically assigned to the object the event happened on.

This can be done by using an init function for the object in which the binding happens ([jsfiddle for tryout](http://jsfiddle.net/Dcerr/1/)):

```
var myObject = {
    init:function(){
        this.downHandler = this.downHandler.bind(this);
    },
    downHandler:function(){
        alert(this.someInfo);
    },
    someInfo:"hi there"
}      
myObject.init();
```

I want to avoid this: Redefining it somewhere else decreases code maintainability. So I'm I'm in search for an solution that keeps the process of binding at the method itself.

I tried immediate function execution already, but at the point of immediate execution, the "this" point towards the "window" object (assuming a browser-context). My trials look like this:

```
var myObject = {
//more code
    downHandler:(function(){
        alert(this.someInfo);
    }).bind(this), //does not work since at the point of immediate execution, the this is assigned to window
//more code
}
```

Can you think of a way that keeps the binding at the event handling function and not in a separate init-function?

Comment: are you open to using libraries like underscore?

Comment: I already got jquery and mootools so I rather would like to avoid additional libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've already got jQuery loaded use [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
var myObject = {
    downHandler: $.proxy(function(){
       alert(this.someInfo);
    }, this)
};
```

If you've got [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org) installed (which I prefer for stuff like this), use `_.bind`

```
var myObject = {
    downHandler: _.bind(function(){
       alert(this.someInfo);
    }, this
};
```

MooTools might have something similar as well -- I've never looked into using it.

Comment: the trouble is that it does require an init function as well, since the "this" at the time of initialization points to the global object, not to the object the function is part of. But it goes in the right direction... lets see what I can make out of it :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObject = {
    clickHandler: function() {
        alert(myObject.someInfo); 
        //returns undefined without execution of init-function
        //returns "hi there" if init ran. 
    },
    someInfo: "hi there"
}

$('#clickMe').on('click', myObject.clickHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

During alert use object name 'myObject' instead of 'this'.

```
var myObject = {
    downHandler:(function(){
        alert(myObject.someInfo);
    }).bind(this), 
  //when 'this' use it alert undefined
  //when 'myObject' use it alert "hi there"
   someInfo:"hi there" 
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you. The problem is that hard-coding the value this should have takes away the useful characteristics "this" has, e.g. being able to borrow the method etc.